# Combine if else and vlookup into one statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel if and else function for calculation]

I'd like to ask how can I use if and else to my calculation in Excel. Here's the case:

> A1=usd, B1=php, C1=conversion amount in usd, D1=total amount in usd

Question: The formula will place in cell d1. I want this way, if I put amount into cell a1 it will only lookup the amount and displayed in cell d1 or if I'm going to put amount in cell b1 and c1, cell d1 calculates the conversion of cell b1 and c1 (a1/c1)? Can you provide me formula or code?

Comment: =IFERROR(SUM(B2/C2),OR(VLOOKUP(A2,A2,1,FALSE))),"") "like this one, can you improve the function cause it does not work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`=IFERROR(IF(A2<>"",A2,B2/C2),"")` 
You can modify the conversion as per your wish.

Note: It will calculate conversion only if the A2 cell is blank or else it will display the value of A2.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I've tried it a while ago and it works! Thankyou so much sir! Great help for my report..